# find: ‘zip’: No such file or directory

Tags: find, zip

I'm using WSL (Ubuntu) and trying to recursively zip the files in a bunch of subfolders.

i.e.

```
Main Folder .
  SubFolder 1's files get zipped into a .zip
  SubFolder 2's files get zipped into a .zip
  SubFolder 3's files get zipped into a .zip
  SubFolder 4's files get zipped into a .zip
  SubFolder 5's files get zipped into a .zip

etc.
```

I nav to the Main Folder, and run this:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -execdir zip -r '{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

Upon doing so, I get spammed with a bunch of:

> find: ‘zip’: No such file or directory

I've also tried the exact same line, using `exec` instead of `execdir` but got the same result. Anyone able to point out the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that error means you have not installed the `zip` command, test with [`command -v zip`](/q/85249/72456); empty output means that is not installed, install `sudo apt install zip`.

---

to `zip` every directory's files individually *excluding* the directories you will need add `-j` option to the `zip` commnad:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir zip -jr '{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

note that you need `-maxdepth` option to specify before `-type d`, also added `-mindepth 1` to ignore zipping current directory; or replace both with [[`! -name . -prune`; Limit POSIX find to specific depth?]](/a/330372/72456), so the command would be:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type d -execdir zip -jr '{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

Alternatively you can use for-loop too:

```
for thing in ./*; do
    [[ -d "${thing}" ]] && zip -jr "${thing}.zip" "${thing}";
done
```

Note that due to use of `-j` option in case there were files with similar name collecting from different subdirectories into single zip file, command will stop zipping because of same files names.